# "Create Random Points" does not accept integer column as "value from input field"

Tags: qgis

Using `QGIS 2.6.1-Brighton` in Ubuntu 14.04

I have a polygon layer loaded from a PostGIS query with int4 values that range from 0 to 3000. When I try using the Random Points tool on this layer, none of the integer columns appear in the dropdown list for "Use value from input field." When I divided the values in a column by 10 to diminish their range (while still using integers) I still could not run the function.

UPDATE:

I saved the query layer to file and reopened it and this still did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I created the layer from the PostGIS query I used the census tract `geoid::bigint` as a gid. In the properties of the layer this field was being considered by QGIS as a QString.

Adding a new column to the layer with value `row_number` and naming it `gid` solved this problem of specifying an input field in `Random Points`